# Object recognition with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to customize this code in such a way so that it can print something if a specific object is present in a frame or print something else if the object is not detected in the frame? If it is not possible then how can i do that? I am completely a beginner in opencv. :)

```
`
import cv2

import time
classNames = []
classFile = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/coco.names"
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

configPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)


def getObjects(img, thres, nms, draw=True, objects=[]):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres,nmsThreshold=nms)
    #print(classIds,bbox)
    if len(objects) == 0: objects = classNames
    objectInfo =[]
    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]
            if className in objects: 
                objectInfo.append([box,className])
                if (draw):
                    cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
                    cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
                    cv2.putText(img,str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
    
    return img,objectInfo


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,640)
    cap.set(4,480)
    #cap.set(10,70)
    
    
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.45,0.2)
        #print(objectInfo)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to print something if a specific object is detected in a frame. There can be a single object or multiple objects, let call them objects of interest (ooi).

What I don't understand is "to print something else if the color is not detected". I'm sure it's a mistake, it must be an object instead of color. Let's now modify the code:

```
import cv2
import time

# define a list of objects of interest here
ooi = ['person', 'car', 'dog']

classNames = []
classFile = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/coco.names"
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

configPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

def getObjects(img, thres, nms, draw=True):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres,nmsThreshold=nms)
    #print(classIds,bbox)
    objectInfo =[]
    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]

            # here we need to insert some lines of code
            if className in ooi:
                print('something')
            else:
                print('something else')

            objectInfo.append([box,className])
            if (draw):
                cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
                cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
                cv2.putText(img,str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
    
    return img,objectInfo


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,640)
    cap.set(4,480)

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.45,0.2)
        #print(objectInfo)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)

        # break the loop if Esc is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
```

Note: I'm leaving the model parameters and other settings as it as assuming everything else is working fine.