# Raspberry image detection code error: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4

I'm doing a project on object and animal recognition with Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. All the libraries are set and the camera is ready but I get the following error:
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
The full code is the following, followed by the error text.

```
import cv2

#thres = 0.45 # Threshold to detect object

classNames = []
classFile = "/home/administrador/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/coco.names"
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

configPath = "/home/administrador/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "/home/administrador/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)


def getObjects(img, thres, nms, draw=True, objects=[]):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres,nmsThreshold=nms)
    #print(classIds,bbox)
    if len(objects) == 0: objects = classNames
    objectInfo =[]
    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]
            if className in objects:
                objectInfo.append([box,className])
                if (draw):
                    cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
                    cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
                    cv2.putText(img,str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)

    return img,objectInfo


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,640)
    cap.set(4,480)
    #cap.set(10,70)


    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.45,0.2)
        #print(objectInfo)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrador/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/object-ident.py", line 50, in <module>
result, objectInfo = getObjects(img,0.45,0.2)
  File "/home/administrador/Desktop/Object_Detection_Files/object-ident.py", line 21, in getObjects
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres,nmsThreshold=nms)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /home/administrador/opencv-4.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

I do not know where this problem comes from, does anyone have an idea? All the libraries are set, Open CV is well installed, etc. I wouyld very muchb appreciate help!!

Comment: You never check whether the `VideoCapture` constructor succeeded in opening the camera, and you never check the value of `success`, even though you capture it (the result of `cap.read()`). One of those probably failed (which will cause `read` to return an empty image) and as a result you're calling `net.detect` with an invalid input argument.

Comment: The problem is coming from this `if className in objects:`

Comment: Look at line 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555702/object-recognition-with-opencv-and-python